# Domain username being added at the end of Domain - Drupal

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal, cpanel, whm

A user has created an account and i have given him access to a cpanel. He gave me the domain and everything is working now. However, when he tries to visit the website and open up links, it automatically adds his username e.g.

www.domain.com/~username/contact-us

Now, when he removes the ~username, the page still shows and its all working.

this is his htaccess file: http://pastebin.com/M8xmg8er

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the base dir in your Drupal `settings.php` / the `.htaccess` is not the problem